# Can someone give me the graph of the function below $f(x)=n$ if $x=\frac{m}{n}$, $gcd(m,n)=1$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise(for irrationals)?

Tags: real-analysis

I want to know how the function looks?

$f(x) = \begin{cases}  n \quad \text{if}\quad x=\frac{m}{n} \quad \text{and}\quad gcd(m,n)=1\\ 0 \quad \text{if} \ \quad x \quad\text{ is irrational}\end{cases}$

I cannot plot the graph with pen and paper.Please help me with the graph.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot plot this with a pen and paper because this is a tricky function. It's closely related to [Thomae's Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function). That function is known to be continuous only at the irrationals but it seems this one is probably not so.

Comment: this function is discontinuous at every point and unbounded in every open interval

Answer (score 0):

I cannot graph it as well but I suspect it'd look really confusing since every rational Number will have an Output being some natural number and It's gonna jump up and down. I imagine the graph as dotted lines at every prime number, 1 and 0 now. And, I think, the higher the value, the less "dotty" it'll be.

[To explain the Image: you can mirror it along both the x and y axis because m/n=(-m)/(-n). I just did a Rough Sketch and this is nowhere near to being exact but it should be able to explain what I mean.9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAPZD.jpg)

Comment: Can you draw a rough sketch of the function or graph it using a software?That would be helpful for me to visualize.

Comment: Whoah. Took me some time figuring out why it wouldn't Display my Image. Deleting Code is never a good Idea...

Comment: It is periodic whith a period of 1.

Comment: Well turns out I can plot it... (referring to my post Saying I can't plot it, not trying to say "well I am better than you". Just to be clear this is self-ironic and not meant to be offensive)